# Selection Sort Error : Wrong Output; Duplicates not sorted

Tags: c#, sorting, selection

My sorting algorithm is giving incorrect results. I have tried identifying the error, but I am not sure why the selection sorting is not working. 
Where do I fix the error in output? 
My output is 
1
4
5
6
7
3
7
9
10
Therefore the 3 in between the 7s is not sorted..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Array = { 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 9, 10 };
        Console.WriteLine("Array before sorting: ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length-1 ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i] + " " );

        }

        SelectionSort(Array);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SelectionSort(int[] Array) // ascending order
    {
        int min;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length-1 ; i++) // go through the list
        {
            min = i; // minimum equals the current position in list
            for (int j = i+1; j < Array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Array[j] < Array[min])
                    min = j; // min equals smallest in list j
                swap(Array, i, min); // swap current position in list i and the smallest position in list j
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Array after selection sort: "); 
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++) // display the sorted list
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int[] Array,int x, int y)
    {
        int temp = Array[x];
        Array[x] = Array[y];
        Array[y] = temp;
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Incidentally, an easy way to show the contents of `Array` on one line is `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Array));`. You could have put that after the line that does the swap and seen that things were being swapped when they shouldn't be, which might lead you to wonder if the swap line was in the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] Array = { 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 9, 10 };
    Console.WriteLine("Array before sorting: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length-1 ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Array[i] + " " );

    }

    SelectionSort(Array);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void SelectionSort(int[] Array) // ascending order
{
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length-1 ; i++) // go through the list
    {
        min = i; // minimum equals the current position in list
        for (int j = i+1; j < Array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (Array[j] < Array[min])
                min = j; // min equals smallest in list j
        }
        swap(Array, i, min); // swap current position in list i and the smallest position in list j
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Array after selection sort: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++) // display the sorted list
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Array[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static void swap(int[] Array,int x, int y)
{
    int temp = Array[x];
    Array[x] = Array[y];
    Array[y] = temp;
}
```

> the swap should be out of the inner for loop. First you want to find the smallest number then you would like to swap it with the current element. In your code it was swapping every time it got a smaller number.

Comment: No need to post entire code when there is change in one line. Please post only part of code with changes (outer `for` loop)